# Chrome Extension (background/service): How do I find what type of event to listen for? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, code-injection

I am writing a chrome extension extension for an auto repair POS (ShopWare: [www.shop-ware.com](http://www.shop-ware.com)). My extension takes the workflow page (see images below) and turns it into a 'dispatch board' that is displayed on a big screen out in a shop for auto technicians to view incoming repair orders.

My extension removes unnecessary elements, enlarges the technician names, and causes incoming repair orders to blink until the technician 'accepts' the order on his/her personal device.

Problem:
I was unable to enlarge the text of the technician names with CSS injection. I had to handle it programmatically:

```
const addStyleProp = () => {
  const className = "section-title";
  const styleObj = { "font-size": "40px" };
  elms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (let elm in elms) {
    let curr = elms[elm];

    if (typeof curr === "object") {
      try {
        Object.assign(curr.style, styleObj);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          "Error attempting to change styling on the current node.",
          elm
        );
      }
    }
  }
};

addStyleProp();
```

The issue I am having is, whenever a repair order is transferred to the technician, it triggers a soft reload, that is, it reloads the components, including the text that I have modified with my script. I am now trying to add an event listener to catch that, but I can't figure out what the event is. I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('workorders-index').addEventListener('change',addStyleProp);
//add a DOM listener to handle changes to the DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addStyleProp);
```

Here is the page source before my insertion:

```
<h4 class="section-title">
  <i class="icon-staff blue"></i>
    George
  <span class="assigned-work-orders">
    <i class="icon-car-fa6"></i>
    17
  </span>
</h4>
```

Here is the POS source after my extension:

```
<h4 class="section-title" style="font-size: 40px;">
  <i class="icon-staff blue"></i>
    George
  <span class="assigned-work-orders">
    <i class="icon-car-fa6"></i>
    17
  </span>
</h4>
```

Whenever an order is transferred, the element reverts to the original source. When I try CSS injection, there is no change to the text; however, the CSS that I injected to cause the elements to blink work just fine. I feel that injecting the style sheet would be the best way to go here, but I can't figure out how to make it work. So, how can I either
A.) change via CSS injection
B.) catch the event when the text reverts?

Here is a snippet of my background.js and blink.css. Note: the CSS setting font-size does ***NOT WORK***, hence my 'enlarge-text.js script.

Hope I haven't been too convoluted! I'd appreciate any thoughts on how I can do this better.

background.js:

```
const scriptFiles = ["scripts/removeElements.js", "./scripts/enlarge-text.js"];

const cssFiles = ["./css/blink.css"];

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    text: "",
  });
});

const swRegex = new RegExp(".shop-ware.com");

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  //Check to see if we're on shopware. If not, bail. 
  if (!(tab.url.search(swRegex) > 0)) {
    return;
  }

  const state = await chrome.action.getBadgeText({ tabId: tab.id });
  //Already on. Notihng to do here!
  if (state === "ON") {
    return;
  }

  //set action badge to state
  await chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    tabId: tab.id,
    text: "ON",
  });

  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    files: scriptFiles,
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
  });

  /**Blink the  in-transition class and enlarge text*/
  await chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
    files: cssFiles,
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
  });
});
```

blink.css:

```
.in-transition{
    animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) none infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
    to{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

h4.section-title {
    font-size: 40px;
}

i.muted {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

This is the view before I activate my service:
[image: View before service]

View after my service:
[image: view after service]

Comment: Try adding `font-size: 40px !important;` to the injected CSS file (**blink.css**). If that doesn't work, take a look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated ... put this in background.js it should capture it. It's helpful for single page apps that update the page without a reload. tabs onUpdated captures the page change event

Comment: Use `MutationObserver` in the injected code to detect "soft reload" and restore your UI.

Comment: @Titus -- That worked!     font-size: 40px !importan; is what it took! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titus posted the following answer that solved the issue without having to add an event listener. It's much cleaner than my approach to handling it programmatically!

Titus answer:
Try adding font-size: 40px !important; to the injected CSS file (blink.css). If that doesn't work, take a look at MutationObserver – 
Titus